# How do I fix Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 for SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to insert a weapon into my server. But every time I try to execute I getting the message " Column count doesn't match value count at row 1".

I looked over everything, and everything seems to be fine. Can you guys help me?

```
INSERT INTO item_template (entry, class, subclass, unk0, name, displayid, Quality, Flags, BuyCount, BuyPrice, SellPrice, InventoryType, AllowableClass, AllowableRace, ItemLevel, RequiredLevel, RequiredSkill, RequiredSkillRank, requiredspell, requiredhonorrank, RequiredCityRank, RequiredReputationFaction, RequiredReputationRank, maxcount, stackable, ContainerSlots, stat_type1, stat_value1, stat_type2, stat_value2, stat_type3, stat_value3, stat_type4, stat_value4, stat_type5, stat_value5, stat_type6, stat_value6, stat_type7, stat_value7, stat_type8, stat_value8, stat_type9, stat_value9, stat_type10, stat_value10, dmg_min1, dmg_max1, dmg_type1, dmg_min2, dmg_max2, dmg_type2, armor, holy_res, fire_res, nature_res, frost_res, shadow_res, arcane_res, delay, ammo_type, RangedModRange, spellid_1, spelltrigger_1, spellcharges_1, spellcooldown_1, spellcategory_1, spellcategorycooldown_1, spellid_2, spelltrigger_2, spellcharges_2, spellcooldown_2, spellcategory_2, spellcategorycooldown_2, spellid_3, spelltrigger_3, spellcharges_3, spellcooldown_3, spellcategory_3, spellcategorycooldown_3, spellid_4, spelltrigger_4, spellcharges_4, spellcooldown_4, spellcategory_4, spellcategorycooldown_4, spellid_5, spelltrigger_5, spellcharges_5, spellcooldown_5, spellcategory_5, spellcategorycooldown_5, bonding, description, PageText, LanguageID, PageMaterial, startquest, lockid, Material, sheath, RandomProperty, RandomSuffix, block, itemset, MaxDurability, area, Map, BagFamily, TotemCategory, socketColor_1, socketContent_1, socketColor_2, socketContent_2, socketColor_3, socketContent_3, socketBonus, GemProperties, RequiredDisenchantSkill, ArmorDamageModifier, ScriptName, DisenchantID, StatsCount)
VALUES (12345, 2, 8, -1, "Million Souls", 71781, 5, 0, 1, 20000, 900000000, 17, -1, -1, 900, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,  1, 98000,  3, 99890,  7, 99999,  4, 99999,  6, 99999,  38, 99999,  42, 99999,  0, 0,  0, 0,  0, 0, 99999998, 99999998, 0, 9999999, 9999999, 2, 900, 999999, 99999, 999999, 99999, 999999, 99999, 98.2, 0, 0, 17713, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 18060, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 18060, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 35844, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 35844, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, "Death", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 900, 0, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'internalitemhanler', 0, 10);
```

I deleted all the empty columns that weren't needed and I still get the same error message.

```
INSERT INTO item_template (entry, class, subclass, unk0, name, displayid, Quality, Flags, BuyCount, BuyPrice, SellPrice, InventoryType, AllowableClass, AllowableRace, ItemLevel, RequiredLevel, RequiredSkill, RequiredSkillRank, requiredspell, requiredhonorrank, RequiredCityRank, RequiredReputationFaction, RequiredReputationRank, maxcount, stackable, ContainerSlots, stat_type1, stat_value1, stat_type2, stat_value2, stat_type3, stat_value3, stat_type4, stat_value4, stat_type5, stat_value5, stat_type6, stat_value6, stat_type7, stat_value7, stat_type8, stat_value8)
VALUES (12345, 2, 8, -1, "Million Souls", 71781, 5, 0, 1, 20000, 900000000, 17, -1, -1, 900, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,  1, 98000,  3, 99890,  7, 99999,  4, 99999,  6, 99999,  38, 99999,  42, 99999,  0, 0,  0, 0,  0, 0, 99999998, 99999998, 0, 9999999, 9999999, 2, 900, 999999, 99999, 999999, 99999, 999999, 99999, 98.2, 0, 0, 17713, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 18060, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 18060, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 35844, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 35844, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, "Death", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 900, 0, 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'internalitemhanler', 0, 10);
```

Comment: It appears like you have 1 million columns and about 1.1 million values, those numbers have to match

Comment: This is the text of the query?

Comment: Looks like you need some normalization.

Comment: I have already mentioned that he needs to check the number or rows. He might be missing some rows!

Comment: I see equal numbers of comma's in the two lists.  Double quote on `"Death"`

Comment: According to me, the number are equal! However the row 1 is the issue. You might need to check your query yourself. I mean in an extra page of your website.

Answer (score 0):

Counting the elements in the first and second brackets will reveal, that indeed the count is different.

If I run into this, I rewrite the query into

```
INSERT INTO item_template SET
  entry=12345,
  class=2,
  subclass=8,
  ...
```

which will quickly reveal the culprit.

Comment: That is funny, I counted them and I got 123 for both.  Maybe it was the use of `"` for string constants?

Comment: I think " is ok for string constants in MySql. SQL Server would be another story